# Unable to understand error messege raised by compiler on copy constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, copy-constructor

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class dummy
{
    private:
    int a,b,*p;
    public:
    void setdata(int x,int y,int z)
    {
        a=x;
        b=y;
        p=&z;
    }
    void showdata()
    {
        cout<<"a "<<a<<"b "<<b<<" pointer address c "<<&p<<endl;
    }
    dummy(dummy &d)
    {
        a=d.a;
        b=d.b;
        p=d.p;
        cout<<"a "<<a<<"b "<<b<<" pointer address c "<<&p<<endl;
    }
    dummy(dummy &d)
    {
        d.a;b=d.b;p=d.p;
    }
};
int main()
{
    dummy d1;//error is here;
    d1.setdata(3,4,5);
    dummy d2=d1;
    d2.showdata();
    d1.showdata();
    return 0;
}
```

raised error

> :/root/copy deep shallow/main.cpp|15|error: no matching function for call to ‘dummy::dummy()’|

I am unable to understand why the error messege is raised and what is the solution for this issue

Comment: Shall you declare the constructor in your class ? `dummy();`

Comment: *"`//error is here;`"* - But you don't do a copy here, so what does the copy c'tor have to do with it?

Comment: You need to declare your default constructor as `default`. Compiler won't generate it if you have declared other constructors. Vote to close as typo.

Answer (score 1):

The class does not have the default constructor because there is the explicitly defined copy constructor

```
dummy(dummy &d){a=d.a;b=d.b;p=d.p;}
```

(that shouuld be declared with the parameter `const dummy &`)

However in this declaration

```
dummy d1;
```

there is needed the default constructor that is absent.

You have explicitly to define the default constructor.

Take into account that for example this member function

```
void setdata(int x,int y,int z)
{a=x;b=y;p=&z;}
```

leads to undefined behavior because the pointer `p` will have an invalid value after exiting the function because the local variable (parameter) `z` will be destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

```
dummy()
{
}

dummy(dummy &d)
{
    a=d.a;
    b=d.b;
    p=d.p;
    cout<<"a "<<a<<"b "<<b<<" pointer address c "<<&p<<endl;
}
```

This will fix your issue.

In this way you define a **default constructor** (1st) and a **copy-constructor** (2nd)

In your code you provided no default constructor and two copy constructor, so compiler will complain about the absence of constructor first, but when will you'll solve that it will raise another error due to ambiguos copy constructors (compiler will tell you I don't know which one call).

As third error, setData() will lead to undefined behaviour of p being invalid after destruction of z.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not with copy-constructor, but with default constructor.
Whenever you write a class in C++, the compiler will generate a set of default functions, so you don't have to type them explicitly. Those are:

- Default constructor: `dummy::dummy()`
- Copy constructor: `dummy::dummy(const dummy&)`
- Copy assignment operator:  `dummy& dummy::operator=(const dummy&)`
- Destructor: `dummy::~dummy()`

In C++11 standard you also get move constructor and move assignment operator, but these are not important here.

Compiler adds these to any class for you, but **if you define any constructor, it won't generate implicit default constructor**.

If you want to have default constructor (and be able to use `dummy d1;` in code), add the following constructor definition to the class:

```
dummy(){}
```

or better, if you use C++11 standard:

```
dummy() = default;
```

---

*Side note*: you don't need explicit copy constructor in this case. Your implementation simply copies content of every field to new object, and thus implicit copy constructor (generated by compiler) would be enough.